# Como usar ChatKit en mi app para Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Quiero implementar la librería chatkit, en mi aplicación, pero no lo logro, alguien lo ha hecho? Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Lo recomendable en estos casos es que muestres los pasos que estas siguiendo y señalar claramente en donde tienes el problema. Te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!